# Cosmos DB query on a sub section for a specific document

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

**ANSWER:**
Seems like you need to do a join:

```
select value g from c 
join g in c.groups
where c.id='2' and g.id=2
```

**ISSUE:**

I am trying to query a subsection of a specific document:

```
[
    {
        "name":"name1",
        "id":1 ,    
        "groups":[
            {
                "name":"name1",
                "id":1
            },
            {
                "name":"name2",
                "id":2
            }
        ] 
    },
    {
        "name":"name2",
        "id":2 ,    
        "groups":[
            {
                "name":"name3",
                "id":1
            },
            {
                "name":"name4",
                "id":2
            }
        ] 
    }
]
```

I want following:

```
{
   "name":"name4",
   "id":
}
```

I have tried following:

```
select c.groups from c  where c.id=2 and c.groups.id=2
```

But I get no results. Any ideas how to make a correct query? Notice json is just for sample purpose, in my application there are more nested childs. These also needs to be included.

Answer (score 0):

Basically they have provided the ways to do this in the azure CrudRepository but if we run the direct query, we need to use like below

[image: Query snapshot]

Comment: Wont your match only succeed if first item is "snacks"?

Comment: Yes, Thats what I wanted to show in snapshot, so this document will come in result when first item's name is snacks. For example to get Popcorn we can use food.tags[1].name= "popcorn". In Azure CrudRepository they provided way to lookup nested elements but in case of query we need to use like this only

Comment: But I dont know what the index for the specific item is. I want the element name="Snack" where ever the element is under tags.

Comment: I actually found a solution, not beautiful but it works. If I do a join it works. I just don't get why a join is needed for a query that just goes within a single document.